# Best practice for Android Room database design: using multiple classes/interfaces or multiple queries

Tags: android, android-room

I'm newbie to android and am learning the basics of kotlin/Room. As I head down the rabbit hole of data classes, DAOs joining tables, I am trying to understand **why so many table/interfaces are used where multiple queries could achieve the same outcome?**

Example: an application contains an address book of business contacts. A user can select one or more contacts for their address book from a large list. The aim is to only populate the users address book with the information of the contacts they have selected.

This would require:

- A User table: containing unique user information for many users (userId, name, address...etc.)
- A Contacts table: containing unique contact information for many contacts (contactId, name, address...etc.)
- A joining table: containing the contact selections of each user (userId and contactId)
- A UserWithContacts table: containing embedded user objects with a relation to the contact object in the joinging table.

The purpose of the UserWithContacts table as I understand it is to query directly and get a list of contact objects that have been selected by a specific user.

This structure, with adjoining DAOs, makes for a number of classes/interfaces/etc to keep track of.

Why is it better to take this approach and not simply query the joining table for a list of contactIDs based on a given userId, followed by a second query that returns the contact objects from the contact table with contact information? This would not required the additional UserWithContacts table or DAO interface.

For Example:

```
//Get a list of contactId's that have a common UserId
@Query("SELECT contactId FROM joiningTable WHERE userId =:userId")
fun getAllUserContactIds(userId: String): List<String>

//Get a list of Contacts objects from are contained within a list of Contact Ids
@Query("SELECT * FROM contactTable WHERE contactId IN (:contactIds)")
fun getAllUserContacts(contactIds: List<String>): List<Contact>
```

This pair of queries provides an equivalent list of Contact objects that can be used to populate the address book.

Can anyone describe why it is preferred to use multiple classes/interfaces instead of multiple queries?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: you say you'd need a whole list of tables to achieve this. i could argue that i could store all that data into one model and into one table by using a "document" approach, so that i wouldn't need relationships. if you're following a tutorial,  the tutorial is probably there to teach you _how to do_ something, they might not care if it's the best way _to be doing_ that something

Comment: Hi @a_local_nobody , thanks for the comment. Could you give a quick high level explanation of what you mean by a "document" approach? 
You're right right on the money, the question essentially stems from having worked through a number of tutorials to implement a handful of tables and queries. However, creating a unique table and DAO for every list used in a more complex database seems like overkill. So I thought before moving on with just the 'how' I would ask for input on the 'best way'.

Comment: search for noSql